# Выравнивание элементов матрицы python

Tags: python, матрицы, список, шахматы

решил сделать простую шахматную доску, для выставления фигур на нее. С логикой вроде бы все понятно, хромает только вывод. Все символы храню в списке, есть ли какой-то способ сохранить квадратность доски, то есть не применять табуляцию, как показано на картинке, при сделать все ровно. Я не хочу использовать tkinter, а обойтись только консолью.

[image: результат, который меня не устраивает]

[image: табуляция не выход]

Код:

```py
import string

def create_clear_board(): 
    abc = string.ascii_uppercase[:8]
    board = [['⬜⬛'[(j + i) % 2] for j in range(8)] for i in range(8)]
    for i in range(8):
        board[i].insert(0, i + 1)
    board[2][3] = '♖'
    board.append(' '+abc)
    return board

for i in create_clear_board():
    print(*i)
```

Comment: символы одинаковые по размерам? покажите, как вы выводите это сейчас?

Comment: в том то и дело, что символы разные

Comment: def create_clear_board():
    abc = string.ascii_uppercase[:8]
    board = [['⬜⬛'[(j + i) % 2] for j in range(8)]
            for i in range(8)]

    for i in range(8):
        board[i].insert(0, i + 1)
    board[2][3] = '♖'
    board.append(' '+abc)
    return  board

for i in create_clear_board():
    print(*i)

Comment: Вы хотите делать это именно используя print, или может вы не против модуля curses?

Comment: @ShamusRezol не против

Comment: @ShamusRezol но как быть с подписью ниже, я думаю, все равно кривовато будет

Comment: в голову всякие дурные идеи лезут, подрубить математическую библиотеку и рисовать графики, оси подписать, но это уже не консоль и проще pygame или tkinter подрубить

Comment: а если использовать "□■"?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru это то, что я и делал

Comment: @СерёжаТепляков Нет, это разные символами. С мелкими квадратами нормально работает, а с крупными нет, они, видимо, крупнее, чем обычные буквы.

Answer (score 0):

А если попробывать так? Используя `format` для вывода:

```py
import string

def create_clear_board(): 
    abc = string.ascii_uppercase[:8]
    #board = [[ "⬜⬛"[(j + i) % 2] for j in range(8)] for i in range(8)]
    board = [[ "□■"[(j + i) % 2] for j in range(8)] for i in range(8)]
    for i in range(8):
        board[i].insert(0, i + 1)
    board[2][3] = '♖'
    board.append(' '+abc)
    return board

for i in create_clear_board():
    for m in i:
        print('{:>2}'.format(m), end='')
    print()
```

Вывод:

```
 1 □ ■ □ ■ □ ■ □ ■
 2 ■ □ ■ □ ■ □ ■ □
 3 □ ■ ♖ ■ □ ■ □ ■
 4 ■ □ ■ □ ■ □ ■ □
 5 □ ■ □ ■ □ ■ □ ■
 6 ■ □ ■ □ ■ □ ■ □
 7 □ ■ □ ■ □ ■ □ ■
 8 ■ □ ■ □ ■ □ ■ □
   A B C D E F G H
```

Но, лучше использовать графическую библиотеку.

Comment: С вашими символами работает и без всяких форматов )

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну клиент говорил `это то, что я и делал` )